# Storing objects in multiple locations

Tags: java

I have a 'Block' object that needs to be accessed by its location, but I also need to access it by its ID and its 'update interval' (the interval at which it gets redrawn).

Originally I was storing everything in a map with the location as key and iterating through the map to find update interval and ID. I would like a faster method and was thinking about having multiple maps with different values as keys.

Is this a good way of doing things? It would seem to me to be a huge waste of space as you have object references duplicated in multiple areas which would all need to be updated if a new object is created.

Example:

```
class Block {
    private final int id;
    private final Location location;

    public Block(int id, Location location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

Way with one map:

```
private Map<Location, Block> blocks = new HashMap<Location, Block>();

public Block getBlock(Location location) {
    return blocks.get(location);
}

public Block getBlock(int id) {
    for (Block block : blocks.values()) {
        if (block.getId() == id) {
            return block;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Way with two maps:

```
private Map<Location, Block> locationsToBlocks = new HashMap<Location, Block>();
private Map<Integer, Block> idsToBlocks = new HashMap<Integer, Block>();

public Block getBlock(Location location) {
    return locationsToBlocks.get(location);
}

public Block getBlock(int id) {
    return idsToBlocks.get(id);
}
```

Comment: "It would seem to me to be a huge waste of space..."  A.K.A., the old Time-Space-Tradeoff.  Sometimes, faster algorithms require more memory.

Comment: "Is this a good way of doing things?" Sounds good to me. Note that storing extra references is cheaper than storing whole new copies of the same object.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tradeoffs.

### Option 1: Simple

Hash map of Id to Block, for your find by Id it is straightforward and then for find my location you want to iterate through the values of the map. I am not sure what your location object is, but is coordinates? This method will allow your feature to grow to find block nearby locations, maybe. I get worried when I see complex object as keys in a hash map as you will have to make sure to implement equals and hash code correctly based on your business logic. Guava library has always nice functional ways of filtering a collection by a filter function. (Like Fluent Iterable)

### Option 2

Your way, just make sure you implement hash code and equals. Can you tell us more what this location object is?

Comment: The location object is some xyz coordinates of the object, I need to be able to access this fast and often which is why I was thinking of making it a key to the map.